Why does Kotlin allow delegation to extension properties with no backing fields?
I understand why Kotlin doesn't allow initializing extension properties such as
val SomeClass.anExtensionProperty = "can't do this"

because there is no backing field to hold the value.  And I understand that you can use a get()'ter because it doesn't hold state, like this:
val SomeClass.anExtensionProperty get() = "you CAN do this"

because it's calculated on the fly and there's no state to hold.
So I was surprised to find you can do this:
val SomeClass.anExtentionsionProperty by lazy{
   "you CAN do this, but why?"
}

In my mind, when using by delegation normally (not with an extension) you are "setting" a property to reference a delegate, which means storing a reference (i.e. state) to an instantiated object.  That seems to go against the restrictions imposed on extension properties.
Why is this allowed?  What's going on under the hood?

When we use the by operator, the compiler calculates the value on the right side and stores the delegate in the current variable scope. If we do this in the function, delegate is stored as a local variable. If we are in the class, it is stored as a member. If we're in the top-level scope, it is stored in the top-level scope.
Your case is the last one. We are in the top-level scope, so we create a delegate in the top-level scope. It doesn't create separate lazy objects per each instance. It creates a single global one and shares it across all instances. We can easily verify this:
fun main() {
    val c1 = SomeClass()
    println(c1.anExtentionsionProperty)
    val c2 = SomeClass()
    println(c2.anExtentionsionProperty)
}

class SomeClass

val SomeClass.anExtentionsionProperty by lazy{
    println("hello")
    "you CAN do this, but why?"
}

This code prints the "hello" only once, because both instances share the same lazy.
We can also verify this in the bytecode:
public final class Test1Kt {
  private final static Lkotlin/Lazy; anExtentionsionProperty$delegate
}

It created a static field in the Test1Kt class (file was named test1.kt) and there it stored the Lazy object. Then it reads it whenever we access the anExtentionsionProperty.
Update
It may be confusing that the delegate has a different scope than the property itself. But I feel this happens only if we look at this code line from incorrect angle. Similarly as the code:
val bar = getFoo() + 1

is an equivalent of:
val foo = getFoo()
val bar = foo + 1

The same happens here. Code:
val SomeClass.anExtentionsionProperty by getFoo()

Is an equivalent of:
val foo = getFoo()
val SomeClass.anExtentionsionProperty by foo

While we are "executing" this line of code, we immediately calculate the value on the right side and implicitly "remember" it. Then we use the remembered value. Scoping is one potentially confusing part. Another is that some people might think the above code calls getFoo whenever we access the anExtentionsionProperty. Which is also not true.

This explains why it can work but not why the restriction is different than in the first case. The first case could also compile to a static backing field. Also, I’m away from computer and thinking this lazy property wouldn’t make logical sense if the lazily computed value is dependent on anything that would cause it to compute something different depending on which instance of the class you called it on first. It is highly surprising behavior to me that the compiler allows this because it violates the principle that there are no conceptually static members in Kotlin.

In my head these two cases are not really comparable. I'm not sure if I can explain this, but by implicitly "remembers" the delegate somewhere. Delegate is a separate thing than the property we define, and it is stored "just now" or "as we execute the code". This is similar to closures where the compiler has to figure out how to store variables to share them between scopes.

@Tenfour04 I updated my answer and added an explanation on how I personally see this :-)

@Tenfour04 And answering your second concern about using the first instance to calculate the shared value. No, this is not happening here. Again, the expression on the right side of by doesn't run in the context of the receiver. It is calculated first and then its result is remembered and "passed" to the property.

= implicitly remembers the value of the field somewhere, so I’m not seeing why it should be treated differently. by adds a level of indirection to the accessors, but you are still assigning something to a backing field. It would of course be confusing if the type of the property were mutable because all instances would be sharing the same instance of that mutable class, which is why it rightly should be banned. I think both cases should be banned.

My point was that having all instances share a reference to something that is potentially mutable is super confusing because properties typically behave as members of a class instance. Now there is a special case where delegated properties must be thought of as static, an exception to the rule that only top-level stuff behave statically.

@Tenfour04 They are not entirely static, because the delegate receives the instance when accessing the property. I think there could be potential use cases for this feature. Anyway, my point is that maybe it was allowed not by a conscious decision, but is a side-effect of how delegated props work in general. They simply didn't introduce an exception for this specific case. But this is guessing. It would be nice to get a comment by Kotlin authors or find a corresponding design document or something.
